# Swiper has more items than should be

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

When [Swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper) (flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6) has loop false and layout stack it has one more widget during swipe.

Did someone face the same problem?

What could be done with this?

I will appreciate any help you provide.

To reproduce my issue use the code below and add an itembuilder

```
Swiper(
loop: false,
layout: SwiperLayout.STACK)
```

Comment: Have you read the flutter document properly?

Comment: Are you referring to the flutter_swiper package? You have to specific and clear in your question.
Please read the question guidelines to improve your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Corrected the question. I use flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6

Answer (score 0):

I used the example from the package and added the two configuration properties you mentioned. The only error I received was requiring to set the `itemWidth` property required when setting the `SwiperLayout.STACK` layout value. After doing that, I have found no issues:

```
Swiper(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
    return new Image.network("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",fit: BoxFit.fill,);
  },
  itemWidth: 350,
  itemCount: 3,
  pagination: new SwiperPagination(),
  control: new SwiperControl(),
  loop: false,
  layout: SwiperLayout.STACK
),
```

Your issue might be with your itemBuilder. You should share that part of the code.